Override 'New Account' lookup input field with flow
I have standard object Campaign where I have custom field My_Company__c which is Lookup(Account) data type. When I click on this field and want to create new Account by clicking on 'New Account'.
I want to override this button by custom flow. How I can do that?


You can make an action override, but be aware it will affect every place that creates a new account, not just on campaigns. You may want to instead create a Quick Action on Campaigns so that there's a separate button to use.

@sfdcfox It is ok. Can you post it as answer with steps to do it please?

Before I write up an answer, I'd like to know more about what you're trying to do. What does this flow do? When do you want to use the flow?

@sfdcfox Instead of standard Account creating I have created a flow. And on New it's redirecting to flow. So now when I click on New Account I want to redirect to flow as well

@sfdcfox Can you share your solution please?
